# How can I avoid AOT build error during publish build in Blazor Wasm?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, ahead-of-time-compile

I have a Blazor Wasm app. There is a class FooData with several properties.

```
public class FooData
{
    public int Foo1 { get; set; } = -999;
    public double Foo2 { get; set; } = -999d;
    ...
}
```

And there is a class BarUnits

```
public class BarUnits : ComponentBase
{
    public IEnumerable<FooData> IFooDataS { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        LoadFooData();
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void LoadFooData()
    {
        var h1 = new FooData { Foo1 = 1, Foo2 = 2d, ...};
        var h2 = new FooData { Foo1 = 3, Foo2 = 4d, ...};
        ...
    
        IFooDataS = new List<FooData> { h1, h2, ... h1400};
    }
}
```

FooData contains about 100 properties and `LoadFooData` creates 1400 `new FooData`. During development, this is not a problem, but a publish build with enabled AOT compilation fails.

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.16\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(511,5): Error : Precompiling failed for C:[...]\obj\Release\net6.0\linked<appName>.dll.

I tried the following:

1. I reduced `IFooDataS = new List<FooData> { h1, h2, ... h1400};` to `IFooDataS = new List<FooData> { h1, h2, ... h670};` but kept the unused `var h671 =`  to `var h1400 =` . This resulted in a working publish build.
2. With `IFooDataS = new List<FooData> { h1, h2, ... h671};` (one more item) the publish build does not work.
3. But when I now comment out the unused items `var h1390 =`  to `var h1400 =`  the publish build works.
4. Splitting and concatenating does not work: `IFooDataS = IFoo1.Concat(IFoo2).Concat(IFoo2);` results in a publish build error.

How could I make the publish build work?
(I know, getting the data from a database instead of hard coding it, would be more efficient, but that's how I get the data.)

Comment: Have you thought about just splitting that method up into smaller methods that each add 5-600 new items - I mean if you are really going to have to stick to doing it in code like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, Mister Magoo's workaround works.
With updating the project from .net6 to .net7 it works without the workaround.